# How do I remove the block when Selenium throws a pageLoadTimeout exception?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm loading a list of uris into a Java program, and then for each uri, I use selenium to navigate to the page and perform some analysis. However, I'd like to limit the wait time and just skip pages if they're taking too long to load. For example, I navigate to google and it takes like 5 seconds. But then I navigate to some random Chinese site and 30 seconds passes and the server still hasn't responded- Firefox just sits there spinning that little waiting circle.

Selenium appears to throw an exception if I use pageLoadTimeout, but it still sits there for the server to return something before moving on. I'd like to just skip it at the moment it hits the timeout, because otherwise the timeout is quite useless.

Here is the entire bit of code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class scout  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("SeleniumProfile");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(3,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        BufferedReader in = null;
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {   
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scoutLinks.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                myList.add(str);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(String item : myList ){
            try {
                driver.get(item);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        }
        //Quit
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Note I set the timeout to 3 milliseconds to be ridiculous for testing purposes so it would timeout on just about every site. It throws the exception, but then still just sits there waiting for the GET request to go through

UPDATE: Here is the stacktrace when it throws the TimeoutException, when I enable the stacktrace

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page load.
Command duration or timeout: 56 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.ver
sion: '1.7.0_10'
Session ID: e7c34ae4-027c-4bd4-974e-f314b9aa5c74
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=22.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
    at scout.main(scout.java:36)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Timed out waiting for page load.
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:32:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_10'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.get/<(file:///C:/Users/Nate/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7949477209431295646webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8312)
        at <anonymous class>.WebLoadingListener/e(file:///C:/Users/Nate/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7949477209431295646webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:3263)
        at <anonymous class>.WebLoadingListener/<(file:///C:/Users/Nate/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7949477209431295646webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:3270)
        at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/Nate/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous7949477209431295646webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:386)
```

Comment: Is this resolved or not? What happens if you try to programatically press an Escape key on the error to stop the browser and regain control of WebDriver? You can try both [`new Actions(driver).sendKey(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) and the [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Comment: Interesting. The answer below seems to address the problem but in the interest of optimization I'm still going to look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Scout  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("SeleniumProfile");
        WebDriver driver = null;


        BufferedReader in = null;
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {   
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scoutLinks.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                myList.add(str);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(String item : myList ){

            try {
                if(driver == null)
                {
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                driver.get(item);
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Did not get url");
                driver.quit();
                driver = null;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this belong to your other answer, or is it a completely new solution? Could you merge it into one answer? The Edit button is your friend :).

Comment: It does not belong to the other answer. Although both look the same this was an after thought after I saw the full code.

Comment: Excellent solution, I'm going to choose this as best answer, although it would be best if there were a way to, instead of doing driver.quit, it just goes to the next one on the list, but I think this may be a Selenium issue.

My computer is quite slow when starting firefox that it ends up taking longer in some cases than if I had just waited for the page to load. Either way, this is a good answer

Comment: Found another work around. Once you get the report some URL did not open instead of killing the browser, you can navigate to google. You told google for sure opens in couple of seconds. Once it opens you can open the next link in the list. Change the catch code as follows.                                                         }catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Did not get url " + item);
                driver.get("http://www.google.com");
            }                                                                      driver.quit();

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch block for the driver.get() code. In the catch you can actually print the url for which the page did not load. Do not print the stack trace in the catch block. This will stop the execution again.

Comment: This was something I tried before I posted here, to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post the entire try catch for get method? Also the stack trace if you have

Comment: Use the code like something below. Since you are navigating to separate links you can kill the browser if the link does not open and then recreate it. if the link opens then you can continue using the same session. I tried  the code and its working. Let me know if this solves your problem.. Cheers